# How can I clear Textinput after clicking on radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

whenever i click an option i want textinput to get cleared
i have  tried implementing clearbuttonmod but it doesn't work

```
<View>
     <RadioButton.Group
       onValueChange={(value) => setValue(value)}
       value={value}
     >
      
       <RadioButton.Item label="Hate speech" value="Hate speech" />
    
       <RadioButton.Item
         label="I just don't like it"
         value="I just don't like it"
       />
     </RadioButton.Group>
     <Text
       value=""
       style={{
         padding: "3%",
         fontSize: 18,
       }}
     >
       Others
     </Text>
     <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       clearButtonMode="always"
       placeholder="Report..."
       onChangeText={(value) => setValue(value)}
     />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the top, import `useRef`

```
import {useRef} from "react";
```

create a `ref` variable and use it in `TextInput`

```
const InputRef = useRef();
```

then in TextInput

```
 <TextInput
   style={styles.input}
   ref={InputRef}
   clearButtonMode="always"
   placeholder="Report..."
   onChangeText={(value) => setValue(value)}
 />
```

adn in RadioButton

```
<RadioButton.Group
   onValueChange={(value) => {
     setValue(value)
     InputRef.current.clear()
   }}
   value={value}
>
```

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/radio-button-txtinput-clear)